# Phone calls - the other person can't hear me

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, calls, hardware, audio

My phone has just started having a problem where on phone calls, the other person can't hear me. They just hear some static. I can hear them just fine. It's the same whether I call them or they call me. I tried restarting my phone, I looked at the settings and couldn't see anything obvious whereby I could have muted myself. I tried turning the call on Speaker and off again - no difference.

Any ideas?

If it's relevant, my phone is a Samsung Galaxy S running Froyo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the microphone.  Can you record yourself with the Voice Recorder app?  If not, I would suspect you damaged it somehow.

Comment: Yeah, that would be obvious! Don't know why I didn't think of that. Well, without a headset, it only records static. With a headset, I can record voice. I guess that means the default mic is damaged?

Comment: @pfctdayelise Probably, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem with my LG Optimus One (P500). I first suspected the microphone and hence attempted to use voice recorder as suggested by Matthew Read. Since it was working, I became clueless.

After struggling a lot, I realized that I had installed a call recording software.  This call recording software was installed months before and hence I did not suspect it. Even after disabling the software I could not receive calls.  However, the problem was solved once I uninstalled it.

Later I understood that Android SDK does not provide clean solutions to hook into mic (unlike Symbian platform).  Hence call recording software developers are left to use any sort of dirty means (which I am not aware) to make their app work.

So, if you have any such application which plays with mic, just uninstall them and try.